# Comparing penetration testing suites

Tags: attacks, penetration-test, tools

I've been using Backtrack for a while now.  I was wondering if there is anything better, or on par with, that is worth looking into.  Thoughts?

Comment: when i see pentest suites, i think of core, immunity, & metasploit... http://www.n00bz.net/ has a review of each from 2010 if that interests you

Comment: What measures are you using to determine better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thought - **what is it you need?**

If it is a wide set of general purpose tools then yes, Backtrack does come with a wide set of tools, but it doesn't do everything. Other options:

- Darknet have a [top ten LiveCD distros](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2006/03/10-best-security-live-cd-distros-pen-test-forensics-recovery/) from 2008 - some of which have since died, but is a good place to start.
- The [russix LiveCD](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Operating-Systems/Linux-Distributions/Russix-35766.shtml) was ideal for Wireless Penetration Testing - but I think it has been discontinued for a while.
- [Helix](http://www.e-fense.com/helix/) is a forensics and incident response toolkit. Some penetration testing functionality, but the core focus is forensics.

I use all 3 of the above plus other tools - depends on what is needed, and to be honest, having each one on a USB stick or a CD/DVD is pretty easy to carry about.

- If you want really lightweight distros, look at [@atdre's answers to this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2982/485).

Comment: I would just like to add one distro which is pure forensics and IDS toolkit, but to some degree can be used in pentesting. S.M.A.R.T. linux - http://www.asrdata2.com/

Answer (score 2):

If your looking to do web testing samurai has a large amount of web testing tools. However iv never got the automatic scanners working fully, but it does have loads of other useful tools like burpsuite and firefox with a bunch of addons preinstalled.

http://samurai.inguardians.com/

I do agree that it is best to select the tools that you need but these suites are a good base to build on.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested many of them (for many different purpose) and my answer is, that it's pretty cool to have a pentest distro such as backtrack when you start pen-testing, but in the end it's better to pick your own tools up (depending on the job), otherwise there are many tools that you'll never use.

btw another good one was [gnacktrack](http://www.gnacktrack.co.uk/) (but they stopped it due to BT5, but some tools where in GNT and not anymore in BT5)

Helix (Forensic) 3.0 is available for download , but it is not free.

Comment: Why is "there are many tools that you'll never use." a problem?

Comment: Just checked on their webpage - Helix is avaible for download. However, it's not free.

Comment: Actually they include some tools that you'll never use if you run a little pentest company, such as VoIP tools or Web tools or you'll always use one tool for many things ( like a proxy such as the OWASP proxy, and not all the others included) -- For Helix I ment that during a long period it was free to download and that now it's not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One current up-and-coming pen testing distros is [Blackbuntu](http://www.blackbuntu.com/).  There's an active dev group focused on it now and it's definitely worth giving a look.